# Voting for competing answers (Sportsmanship badge)

Tags: support, badges, voting, competing-answers, sportsmanship-badge

If I answer a question and vote for a competing answer, I am on my way to the Sportsmanship badge. What about if I:

a) delete my answer after voting for a competing answer

-- or  --

b) delete my answer *before* voting for a competing answer

-- or  --

c) delete my answer, vote for a competing answer, *get abducted by aliens*, the aliens using my account undelete my answer

Do any of those scenarios count towards the badge?

---

And just for the hell of it - what if I undo my vote for the competing answer?

<sub><sub>This, of course, is not the result of alien abduction. Duh. This would be the result of a kidnapping where the kidnappers force me to undo upvotes under threat of serious injury or death.</sub></sub>

Comment: You forgot the third scenario: where you answer, delete it, vote, then edit and undelete your answer. For everyone's benefit I have added this scenario to your question.

Comment: Alien abduction isn't necessary, they already tap your Internet connection.

Comment: @Sid, what if you vote by accident, immediately click to undo your vote, post a short answer, realize your initial vote was correct, re-vote while still in the vote grace period and then delete your own answer? And what if you then re-undo your vote? Way to only selectively add use cases.

Comment: @Population Demeter, that's why Atwood's Angels added the ability for us to edit questions. You can just add your scenario and so can others until all scenarios are enumerated exhaustively.

Comment: @Sid - I'm glad I ran into you here. I've been meaning to tell you: I don't care how big your hoplite army is, it can never "shoot down" an airplane.

Comment: @JonB. Don't mess with Sid, his words are backed by nuclear weapons!

Comment: Why do people downvoting competing answers?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Currently, the badge logic is:

- your answer has a positive score
- your answer isn't deleted
- <strike>your vote on a competing answer occurs *after* your answer</strike>

Also, for the purposes of all vote-based badges, deleted votes (i.e. votes you undo) are never factored in.

**Edit**

After [intense public outcry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69438/modify-the-competing-answer-rule-to-ignore-when-votes-were-cast), we've removed the restriction that your upvotes on competing answers must occur after your answer.

Comment: #3 there surprises me. What's the reasoning behind it? It's not uncommon for me to scroll down a question, reading the answers, upvoting as I go. When I reach the bottom of the page, I might think "hm, as good as those answers were, none of them mentioned X." Then I'll be in the perfect place to add an answer that does address X. It seems much less natural to make it to the bottom of the page without voting. This might encourage people to answer before reading the existing answers, which is bad; if that was desired, the answer entry box would be on top of the answer list.

Comment: This makes me wonder if your answer has to have a positive score *before* you vote on another answer, too.

Comment: As an aside, it's a shame about the only upvotes count condition, as well as #3: I'm sure I have made over 100 downvotes in the [Significant new inventions in computing since 1980](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432922/significant-new-inventions-in-computing-since-1980) thread – I'd be able to cinch the badge with one answer...

Comment: @Charles: It's called "Sportsmanship", not "Elbowing your way to the top"; why on earth would downvotes count?

Comment: @Ἰησοῦς: It's a joke.

Comment: @Charles: Oh, well. Had I the power, I'd give you a badge for those downvotes. Something like a Purple Heart -- wounded while tending to site quality.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, Is there a time limit between the votes casted and the answer post? Does it count if the answer is posted 1 year after the vote has been casted? Also does voting on multiple answers give you multiple "Sportsmanship"?