# Modify the "competing answer" rule to ignore when votes were cast

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sportsmanship-badge

According to [the announcement by Jarrod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/voting-for-competing-answers-sportsmanship-badge/68156#68156), the logic for the Sportsmanship badge only counts votes that a user casts *after* posting his own answer. I questioned that logic in a comment under the announcement; here's the gist:

> It's not uncommon for me to scroll down a question, reading the answers, upvoting as I go... this badge logic might encourage people to answer before reading the existing answers, which is bad.

Jarrod's reply:

> that's a good point about the Sportsmanship logic possibly discouraging reading all the existing answers.. we'll discuss it.
>   ([source](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/247431#247431))

Has this discussion happened? Just now, I went to a question, started writing an answer, upvoted the existing answer, remembered the timing rule, immediately removed my upvote, finished/posted my answer and then found that I couldn't re-upvote the first answer because it'd been 11 minutes since the initial vote was cast.

In short, I would like to officially feature-request this change to the Sportsmanship logic: **allow votes you cast before you submit your own answer to count towards the badge**.

Comment: +1, That's typically how I use the site as well. If I have something to add by the time that I get to the bottom, I add it.

Comment: *cough* badgewhore *cough*

Comment: Humans are naturally wired to be badgewhores, nothing wrong with that :)

Comment: Yay, I got one :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The restriction that you must upvote other answers *after* answering the question yourself has been [lifted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/voting-for-competing-answers-sportsmanship-badge/68156#68156).  You just need to have upvoted a competing answer.

<sub>And [there was much rejoicing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enSYlCEz5VI).</sub>

Comment: Bounty incoming in 20 hours. Thanks!

Comment: Does it mean that upvotes which are cast *after* your answer doesn't count anymore? That would be a good thing though. It prevents badge gaming by upvoting old competing answers where yours is anyway already the top/accepted answer.

Comment: @BalusC Based on what I've seen, and the wording of the discussion, they still count. How is spreading the wealth, even though your answer has been accepted or is the highest voted, *gaming*? Seems to be exactly [why the Sportsmanship badge exists](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

Comment: @Mark: to vote because of the badge, not because of the sportsmanship. The ones who stop after they get the badge.

Comment: @BalusC badges are there to reinforce and encourage positive actions, not to weed out good intent from bad intent. If the end result is the same, does it really matter if someone did it for the sake of getting the badge or if they did it because they're a good person?

Comment: @Mark: Well, I think you've got a point. Maybe. But if it was me, I would increase the vote count border. Right now it costs basically less than 4 days to get it.

Comment: @BalusC I edited to clarify. Just the fact you upvoted competing *good* content is enough.

Comment: @Jarrod - Thanks, Just got mine :) Ironically, @Popular Demand hasn't gotten one yet. I was sure that changing this would put the number of people who have it at over 1k, but amazingly it's still lower than 500.

Comment: @Tim, I didn't really expect one. I rarely post answers to questions if I agree with one or more existing answers, so there aren't many competing answers around for me to upvote. I figure I'm halfway there.`</wildSpeculation>`