# Do Sportsmanship badge votes count after an answer is accepted?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting, sportsmanship-badge, competing-answers

The Sportsmanship badge is awarded for voting on 100 answers competing with one's own. Do the votes I cast count toward this badge when either of the following circumstances are true?

1. The requestor has already accepted my answer
2. The requestor has already accepted someone else's answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The acceptance of an answer is unrelated to the *Sportsmanship* badge logic.  It's very simple:

- you have an answer posted to the question with a positive score
- you have upvoted one of the other answers

If you have <strike>a hundred answers</strike> upvoted a hundred competing answers that match these criteria, then you will receive the badge.

Here are some related questions:

- [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258)
- [Voting for competing answers (Sportsmanship badge)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/voting-for-competing-answers-sportsmanship-badge)
- [Modify the "competing answer" rule to ignore when votes were cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69438/modify-the-competing-answer-rule-to-ignore-when-votes-were-cast)
- [Are upvotes on competing posts counted per question or per answer for Sportsmanship?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105637/multiple-up-votes-on-one-question)