# Sportsmanship badge: Does answer need +1 -before- voting on a competing answer to count?

Tags: discussion, badges, sportsmanship-badge, competing-answers

I was browsing through [SODE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/815/how-sporting-am-i-sportsmanship-badge) this morning and found [this SODE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/815/how-sporting-am-i-sportsmanship-badge) that claims I have cast 279 competing votes.  Which got me wondering; for a vote to count towards the [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship) badge, do you need to have at least +1 vote count on your own answer ***before*** voting on competing answers?

It is not uncommon for me to upvote other answers before my answers recieve any votes.  If I do that, and *then* my answer gets a vote, does my competing upvote (retroactively) count towards this badge, or no?

> [`Sportsmanship` Up voted 100 competing answers.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/815/how-sporting-am-i-sportsmanship-badge)

---

This is all assuming that the query is sound and still up to date.  It may just be an incorrect query; I am not very good with SQL!

Query is:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

select distinct v2.postid as 'Own', p2.body as 'Own answer', p2.Score as 'Own score'
from votes v2
inner join posts p2 on p2.id=v2.postid
where 
  p2.posttypeid=2 
  and p2.score>0 
  and p2.CommunityOwnedDate is null 
  and p2.OwnerUserId=@UserId
  and exists (select * from votes v1 inner join posts p1 on p1.id=v1.postid
  where p1.ParentId=p2.ParentId)
```

Comment: How does the query fetch your own votes? I don't think that information is available.

Comment: @Null Added the query

Comment: What I am trying to say is that the query is incorrect.

Comment: \@Null @MatthewRead - That makes sense, ty!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meh, even though this links to another MSO post, is *is* the answer. Reposting it as such.

When Sportsmanship was introduced, you did have to cast your vote for competing answers after posting your own answer. I don't know if you had to have a positive score on your answer first.

However, you no longer have to post your own answer before voting for competing answers, according to [this answer by Jarrod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69438/modify-the-competing-answer-rule-to-ignore-when-votes-were-cast/76298#76298) that introduces the rule change. By extension, the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Thanks for that link/info; an interesting read.  I wonder if this query is just wrong.

Comment: @chown The data explorer doesn't include the owners of votes IIRC.  There is no query that can be even remotely accurate unless that is changed, which it won't be due to privacy issues.