# Is the Sportsmanship Badge Broken?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, badges

I'm user 355583 on Stack Overflow. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/815/how-sporting-am-i-sportsmanship-badge) from the data site returns 104 rows; [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1704/how-close-am-i-to-sportsmanship-badge) returns 151 rows.

Either way, I should have the Sportsmanship badge.
I am just wondering if I'm missing something, or if it's possible that the sportsmanship badge is broken.

Comment: @John That’s been lifted; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/voting-for-competing-answers-sportsmanship-badge/68156#68156

Comment: @Bavarious Wonderful!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/975090 got it just 20 hours ago, so it's not completely broken.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what your queries are: *upvotes* are not linked to users in any public data dumps. As far as I know, *favorites* are the only type of votes that are linked to the user who casts them.

Since the Sportsmanship badge requires looking at who cast the vote, there's no way to see your progress (except viewing each post and seeing how many of the competing answers you've upvoted).

Comment: This is correct, the query only tells you how many possible chances you have to upvote competing answers, not how many votes you've cast.

Comment: +1 for a concrete reason why they suck. :P

Comment: @waiwai933 - if indeed this is the case: upvotes are not linked to users, how can the sportsmanship badge can be awarded at all?

Answer (score 7):

More than likely the queries suck.  (It shouldn't be surprising that they differ from reality in addition to each other.)

Comment: Eh, I'm not so sure about that.. I did it and it seemed to be a sane number. And this is recent data dumps.

Comment: If there is something wrong with Query #1, I don't see it... and I looked closely. But since I can't see the actual, current, criteria, it makes it hard to determine where the problem lies.

Comment: @SimonSheehan See the other answer :)

Comment: @MatthewRead Yep, makes sense then. Thanks!