# What are the advantages of exploring SE data via Google BigQuery over the T-SQL data explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I have seen that it's possible to explore Stack Exchange data via [Google BigQuery](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/bigquery-public-data:stackoverflow) as well as via the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com). What are the benefits of this?

As far as I see, the data explorer is T-SQL, which to me seems an advantage in and of itself. I think (but am not sure on this) that BigQuery can be accessed via an API, whereas I'm not sure that the data explorer can.

Is this the only advantage or are there others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google BigQuery, it's easier to combine the tables with other data sources. In SEDE, you're basically limited to what the Data Explorer gives you; external data, including [Stack Exchange information that is not exposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316250/295232), needs to be provided in the query itself via temporary tables and `INSERT` statements ([example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/906091/questions-closed-by-multiple-moderators-networkwide)).

Comment: Thank you @Glorfindel (presumably from Middle Earth?) - when you say 'combine with other data sources'. Do you mean that BigQuery allows you to join completely separate data sources (say GitHub and SE) together? This would be cool

Comment: IIRC you can create your own project and use several external datasets (like Stack Exchange *and* GitHub) in it.