# Sportsmanship Badge Question

Tags: discussion, badges, sportsmanship-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Voting for competing answers (Sportsmanship badge)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/voting-for-competing-answers-sportsmanship-badge)

Suppose I have posted 100 questions. On all these questions there are two answers - one is mine and other is some other users. I upvoted on all answers posted by other users. Will I get sportsmanship badge?

Comment: You can have mine (though don't know if I have one).

Comment: Not really sportsmanship if you're going about it that way :-p

Answer (score 6):

No you won't. You will only get it if all your 100 answers got upvoted too. It only counts for answers where you got a positive score.

The current logic can be found [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68156/172011)